# Delete duplicates dictionary inside list by key

Tags: python-3.x

I'm newbie in python. I have the next list with dictionaries inside.

```
 l = [{'id': 2, 'source_id': 100},
     {'id': 1, 'source_id': 100},
     {'id': 3, 'source_id': 1234},
     {'id': 5, 'source_id': 200},
     {'id': 4, 'source_id': 200}]
```

And I want to get result like:

```
 l = [{'id': 1, 'source_id': 100},
     {'id': 3, 'source_id': 1234},
     {'id': 4, 'source_id': 200}]
```

I understand first step is sorting the list:

```
sorted_sources_list = sorted(l, key=lambda source: source['id'])
```

But I don't know how delete duplicate with the greatest id.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each item and add the item to another empty array, but before you add, check if the item already exists within the new array. If it does, its a duplicate item, but if it doesn't, that's obvious, its not duplicate item.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
getId = lambda x: x.get("source_id", None)
l = list(map(lambda x: list(list(x)[-1])[-1], groupby(sorted(l, key=getId), getId)))
```

Outputs:

```py
[{'id': 1, 'source_id': 100}, {'id': 4, 'source_id': 200}, {'id': 3, 'source_id': 1234}]
```